# UTF8 from DB PHP

Tags: php

I'm storing UTF8 in my database and this all works properly but whenever I retrieve data from the database I get these weird symbols,

Example:
`™` becomes `â„¢`

When I make a connection the DB I use
`array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try changing that to: `1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8'` (this is a known bug in PDO). Also, make sure that both the PHP-file is stored as UTF-8, and that you are using UTF-8 in the database.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie how do I 'store' a php file as UTF-8? I'm using UTF-8 in the database for sure.

EDIT: Changing it to 1002 didn't work.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie well, I added the charset which worked. Thanks.